# How can i override the jquery fileupload plugin option

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I am using jquery fileupload plugin with Jquery UI

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options

I want to overiride the widget options like `maxUploadfilesize`

Current if i overide the setting in main file  `jquery.fileupload-ui.js`

then it works

```
var parentWidget = ($.blueimpFP || $.blueimp).fileupload;
    $.widget('blueimpUI.fileupload', parentWidget, {

        options: {
            // By default, files added to the widget are uploaded as soon
            // as the user clicks on the start buttons. To enable automatic
            // uploads, set the following option to true:
            autoUpload: true,
            //sequentialUploads, true,
            // The following option limits the number of files that are
            // allowed to be uploaded using this widget:
            maxNumberOfFiles: undefined,
            // The maximum allowed file size:
            maxFileSize: 20000000,
            // The minimum allowed file size:
            minFileSize: undefined,
```

Is there any way i can overide that in my html template so that i can have different customization for different html pages

I mean some javvscript code which i can put in template which override the default settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their [documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/API) says that you can override them

Just put this code where u r initializing the plugin

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
    'option',
    {
        maxFileSize: 4000000,
        sequentialUploads: true
    }
);
```